# Probability Problem choosing $6$

Tags: probability

If you have $10$ red marbles and $15$ green marbles in a bag, and you randomly choose $6$, what is the probability that $5$ red marbles will be selected?

Answer (score 2):

$$p(A)=\frac{\binom{10}5.\binom{15}1}{\binom{25}6}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: How many ways are there to choose exactly $5$ red marbles? You may choose any of the $\binom{10}5$ sets of $5$ red marbles and any of the $15$ green marbles to fill out the half dozen, so there are $15\binom{10}5$ ways to get exactly $5$ red marbles. This is the number of succesful outcomes.

- How many (equally likely) possible outcomes are there altogether when you choose $6$ marbles from a set of $25$?
- How do you combine these two numbers to get the probability of a successful outcome?